# Installing Cantera 1.8.0 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, pip, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying a lot to install cantera 1.8.0. It is an older version but i need to install it on my Ubuntu 18.04. I am
[image]

Codeline of the error is

```
/usr/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
  ^
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -O3 -Wall -fPIC build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/src/pycantera.o -L/home/anirudh/Downloads/Cantera/cantera-1.8.0-beta/build/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -L/home/anirudh/Downloads/Cantera/cantera-1.8.0-beta/build/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu -L/usr/local/lib -lclib -luser -loneD -lzeroD -lequil -lkinetics -ltransport -lthermo -lctnumerics -lctmath -ltpx -lctspectra -lconverters -lctbase -lsundials_cvodes -lsundials_nvecserial -lctlapack -lctblas -lctf2c -lctf2c -lctf2c -lm -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/Cantera/_cantera.so -L/usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libsundials_cvodes.a(cvodes.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
Makefile:53: recipe for target '_build' failed
make[1]: *** [_build] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anirudh/Downloads/Cantera/cantera-1.8.0-beta/Cantera/python'
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'python' failed
make: *** [python] Error 2
```

Comment: Please be aware that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which was released in 2018-April (thus the 18.04) had 5 years of *standard* support life, is nearing the end of those five years. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm if your system is still *supported*. Either way, if the machine is on-line, you should plan to *release-upgrade* asap unless you plan to use ESM/Pro, but please note ESM/Pro releases are not on-topic here when standard support ends.

Comment: Sorry about multiple tags. I could not add a new tag ("Cantera") as I am a new member

Comment: My ubuntu is 18 LTS(Bionic) and I am getting this error. I am following this site for installation:                         https://aandreasen.wordpress.com/2010/01/28/installing-cantera-1-8-on-ubuntu-9-10-32-bit/

Comment: The error says "...when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC". Also, how did step 1 go?

Comment: You mean the step before using make command ?.......Yes it was fine..no error.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support